# Getting started with mochiweb and Webmachine?

Tags: mochiweb, webmachine

Mochiweb and webmachine are very promising applications when you see how those who have found they're way around them are using it. I need to be directed to where I can find beginners' tutorials on mochiweb. It appears there is no website dedicated to the framework. I think what I need is a pdf, or a blog site or a tutorial on mochiweb, providing several examples on how to use it. I'm an erlang programmer already, using Nitrogen, Yaws, Mnesia and OTP e.t.c. Please show me the way...

Comment: You should improve your **accecpt rate**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wriaki, a sample app by Basho for Riak, is based on webmachine.

https://github.com/basho/wriaki

There is a video too

http://www.vimeo.com/14275191

Answer (score 9):

On MochiWeb, I wrote http://alexmarandon.com/articles/mochiweb_tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

Nice series:

http://buffered.io/series/web-development-with-erlang/

Comment: 404 - not found. Seems to be no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

[A nice tutorial](http://beebole.com/en/blog/erlang/tutorial-web-application-erlang) on mochiweb, json (video).